# Color Combination

Tags: color, guidelines, feedback, color-scheme, flat-design

I am trying to create a webpage and I don't know much about UX. I am quite confused about the colour combination of text. Like here(in the picture) I used two different colours for the `Title` and `Tag line`. Is it a bad practice to have different colours on the same webpage? What are the recommended ways to choose colours?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Colors can evoke emotion. For example red symbolises passion, blue trustworthiness and green innovation. Just googling 'color emotion' or 'color meaning' and maybe even in combination with the term 'website' can give you lots of reading material.

Choosing colors is also about what looks good, but that's aesthetic and has little to do with UX for it is more a design thing. Again google has a lot of articles on 'choosing colors' for your 'website': lists of useful tools or things you should be aware of.

These are two articles that I found to be useful:
http://designshack.net/articles/inspiration/25-awesome-tools-for-choosing-a-website-color-scheme/
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/website-color-scheme/

Answer (score 2):

**Your colors should *tie into your brand*, should *never overwhelm your users*, and should be *used consistently* in your design.**

While there is deep psychology behind colors, different products treat them in very different ways. For example, red is very often used for warnings or errors. But currently Google products are using red for user inputs like composing an email or uploading a file. In that sense, colors are what you make of them, but they should be consistent throughout *your* personal design.

To note, many well used apps have very small color palettes and this seems to be a good thing. Facebook, LinkedIn and Google+, for example, use no more than 5 colors in their interfaces. And some of those 5 tend to be used very subtly.

At the end of the day, it's highly subjective. Based on your design, I don't see a need for two different colors because your Title and Tag line are already two different weights and two different sizes. But that is a *personal opinion* and also based on the small amount of your design you showed. Honestly I don't think there is a right or wrong answer to this question, it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Marketing plays a huge role in the color palette that you use, which in turn may bring up limitations on what colors you can use. As most marketers know, colors evoke certain emotions and also have very different meanings in different countries. Here's a link to a helpful resource:

https://www.helpscout.net/blog/psychology-of-color/

In terms color choices for certain elements on a site, I usually tend to take the color that pops the most from my palette and use that for any call to actions, buttons, or action items that you need to put emphasis on.

With your screenshot above, it really depends on the context and existing color scheme in which it lies within (the overall site). But keep it simple. Use a bold weight and larger size for the name and a regular-medium weight for the info beneath it. In terms of typefaces, I usually will keep it to a maximum of 2 different font families. There isn't any issue with having them different colors, just as long as it flows with with rest of the site and expresses emphasis on the main items.

For reference on the psychology of colors:
• Red was used to stimulate the body and mind and to increase circulation.
• Yellow was thought to stimulate the nerves and purify the body.
• Orange was used to heal the lungs and to increase energy levels.
• Blue was believed to soothe illnesses and treat pain.
• Indigo shades were thought to alleviate skin problems.